# Storing data frame output from a while loop in R

Tags: r, while-loop

Let's say I have a function called `remove_fun` which reduces the number of rows of a dataframe based on some conditions (this function is too verbose to include in this question). This function takes as its input a dataframe with 2 columns. For example, an input df called `block_2_df` could look likes this:

```
block_2_df
Treatment seq
       1   29
       1   23
       3   60
       1   6
       2   41
       1   5
       2   44
```

For this example, let's say the function `remove_fun` removes 1 row at a time based on the highest value of seq in block_2_df$seq. Applying `remove_fun` once would result in a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
remove_fun(block_2_df)
Treatment seq
   1      29
   1      23
   1      6
   2      41
   1      5
   2      44
```

I.e., the row containing seq==60 in `block_2_df` was removed via `remove_fun`

I can create a while loop which repeats this operation on `block_2_df` via `remove_fun` based on the number of rows remaining in `block_2_df` as:

```
while (dim(block_2_df)[1]>1) {
  block_2_df <- remove_fun(block_2_df)
  print(remove_fun(block_2_df))
}
```

This while loop reduces `block_2_df` until it has 1 row left (the lowest value of `block_2_df$seq`), and prints out the 'updated' versions of `block_2_df` until it is reduced to one row.

However, I'd like to save each 'updated' version of `block_2_df` (i.e. `block_2_df` with 7, then 6, then 5,....,then 1 row) produced from the `while` loop. How can I accomplish this? I know for `for` loops, this could be done by creating an empty list at storing each 'updated' `block_2_df` in the `ith` element in the empty list. But I'm not sure how to do something similar in a `while` loop. It would be great to have a list of dfs as output from this `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create and maintain an index counter yourself. It's a bit more trouble than a `for()` loop, that does it on its own but it's not so difficult.

```
saved <- list()
i <- 1
while (dim(block_2_df)[1]>1) {
  block_2_df <- remove_fun(block_2_df)
  saved[[i]] <- block_2_df
  i <- i + 1
  print(block_2_df)
}
```

Also, you were calling `remove_fun`twice in your loop, that was probably not what you wanted to do. I've corrected that, if I'm wrong please say so.

Comment: I was calling remove_fun twice, but only because my real function outputs two objects (so in my code I had two calls for each of these outputs). This was just what I was looking for though, thank you.